# How to load an image on only front part of a json model object using Three Js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi i am trying to render an image on the model object which is using a json file. I have been able to render the model but the image won't render on the JSON at all.

```
var loader1 = new THREE.AssimpJSONLoader();
loader1.load(modelUrl, function(assimpjson){
                                // console.log(assimpjson.geometry);
                                assimpjson.traverse(function(child){
                                        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                                                // newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(assimpjson, mat);
                                                object_json = assimpjson;
                                                assimpjson.traverse(function(child) {
                                                        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                                                                // I am able to set the color of the child 
                                                                // but how can i set the image on the model?
                                                                // I tried loading the image like this 
                                                                // var image = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/images/image1.jpg');
                                                                // Is there a way than i can directly set the image to the mesh child in here 
                                                                // and give a custom height and width to the image.
                                                                // child.material.color.setHex(0xFFFFFF);
                                                        }
                                                });
                                                assimpjson.scale.x = 30;
                                                assimpjson.scale.y = 30;
                                                assimpjson.scale.z = 30;
                                                assimpjson.position.x = 120;
                                                assimpjson.position.y = -200;
                                                assimpjson.position.z = 0;
                                                assimpjson.updateMatrix();
                                                if (previous) scene.remove(previous);
                                                scene.add(assimpjson);
                                                previous = assimpjson;
                                        }
                                });
   });
```

Thanks a tonnn for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this? -

```
function load_model(modelUrl, texture) {

    var loader1 = new THREE.AssimpJSONLoader();
    loader1.load(modelUrl, function (assimpjson) {
        object_json = assimpjson;
        if (texture) {
            assimpjson.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh && child.material) {
                    child.material.map = texture;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                }
            });
        }

        assimpjson.scale.x = 30;
        assimpjson.scale.y = 30;
        assimpjson.scale.z = 30;
        assimpjson.position.x = 120;
        assimpjson.position.y = -200;
        assimpjson.position.z = 0;
        assimpjson.updateMatrix();
        if (previous)
            scene.remove(previous);
        scene.add(assimpjson);
        previous = assimpjson;
    });
}


// instantiate a loader
let loader_t = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("path", function (texture) {
        load_model(modelUrl, texture);
    },
    // Function called when download progresses
    function (xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function (xhr) {
        console.log('An error happened');
        load_model(modelUrl);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Sourov. Thanks a tonnn for the help but it is mapping the image entirely on the object. i do not want that but to render the image on front part of the model only with custom height and width assigned to the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a texture on certain triangles of your model you can assign a THREE.MultiMaterial (Array of Materials) [MultiMaterial (does not exist any more)](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/MultiMaterial)

Depending if your loader generates Geometry or BufferGeometry you need to assign the wanted material ID to each triangle of your model.

For BufferGeometry you can assign BufferGeometry.groups with { start: Integer, count: Integer, materialIndex: Integer }

For Geometry you need to assign foreach Geometry.faces the Face3.materialIndex with an Integer

Hope this helps.